# Handling unauthorized request in react-query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm having problems using react-query. Whenever the response from the server is Unauthorized, useQuery is returning flags status='success' and isError=false. The server response status is 401 and the content of the json response is `{ error: true, message: 'UNAUTHORIZED' }`. I didn't customize react-query in any way.

I'm not using the *ReactQueryConfigProvider*, or passing any options in the call to customize the behaviour.

This is the call:

```
const { status, data, error } = useQuery(
  ["hotelsList", { token: token }],
  getHotels
);
```

And this is the service:

```
const getHotels = async ({ token }) => {
  const uri = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT_v2 + `/hotels`
  return (await fetch(uri, {
    method: "get",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  })).json()
}
```

Being the token invalid, the server is responding with an 401 status code and my custom json response.

[image: Response code from server is 401]

This is the data and error objects from react-query.

[image: Objects returned by useQuery]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

React-query is agnostic about your API that error is only supposed to change Is when your API doesn't respond that's when you will get an error but if the server responds with 404 or 401 etc react-query won't care because it's a valid response, react-query is only the gateway for the response it doesn't handle it in useQuery, I have made a demo here: you can see that the URL is wrong (points to a 404) and it's returning 404 it won't affect the error value but try to change the API URL to github.x for example, it will fail cause no response has been returned and the error value will change

[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-demo-d11y2?file=/src/ToolTip.tsx)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I added my own response for people in my exact situation, but marked yours as Correct since it's the most important to understand this issue.

Comment: Could you update the Sandbox link? The link is not available.

Comment: @SherlyFebrianti thank you for pointing this out i updated the link for the codesandbox demo

Comment: the link has died again

Answer (score 24):

To expand on Chamsddine response, i needed to throw an error when fetch response was not ok. This enabled all the error flags on react-query.

```
const response = await fetch(uri, {
  method: "get",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
})
if (!response.ok) throw new Error(response.statusText)
return await response.json()
```

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. Refer to the following paragraph from react-query documentation (https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-functions#handling-and-throwing-errors): For React Query to determine a query has errored, the query function must throw.

Answer (score 1):

### For errors like **401**

you should use a global handling style, I mean here is the [best solution](https://github.com/TanStack/query/discussions/1385#discussioncomment-3113979) IMHO

I am attaching the code from the link just in case the link dies for some reason

```
  const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {
        queries: {
            retry: (failureCount, err) => {
                if (err.response?.status === 401) {
                    return false; // do not retry, trigger error
                }

                // otherwise, restore default
                const defaultRetry = new QueryClient().getDefaultOptions().queries?.retry;

                return Number.isSafeInteger(defaultRetry) ? failureCount < (defaultRetry ?? 0) : false;
            },

            onError: err => {
                if (err.response?.status === 401) {
                    // clean up session state and prompt for login
                    // ex: window.location.reload();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});


ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
            <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}> //here is your client with default options
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <AppContextProvider>
                        <App />
                    </AppContextProvider>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </QueryClientProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

in case you use `window.fetch` (not relevant for axios) you should check `err.status` instead of `err.response?.status` and be sure that you throw on cath in your `window.fetch` client

```
.catch(response => {throw response;});
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions works with Typescript, what I did was:

```
 const { isLoading, error, data } = useCampaign()
  let myCustomErrorLet: any = {}
  myCustomErrorLet.data = error
  console.log(myCustomErrorLet?.data?.response);
```