# React-Query how to get error message from onError callback?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have small application where I am using `React-Query`, The problem is that when I try to activate **onError** callback, `React Query` first time checks `onSuccess` callback Even when the post request data is incorrect, and throws an error

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'token' of 'data' as it is undefined.
> at Object.onSuccess

But actual API response is **{response: null, error: "Unauthorised"}
error: "Unauthorised"
response: null**

My problem is that I can't access error response from `onError` callback, What am I doing wrong?

```js
/**
 * /* eslint-disable
 *
 * @format
 */

import { useMutation } from 'react-query';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthController from '../../../controller/auth';
import { useToasts } from 'react-toast-notifications';

const Login = () => {
  return AuthController.Login('user4', 'wrongpass');
};

export default function useUserLogin(setCheckTokenStatus) {
  const { addToast } = useToasts();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return useMutation(Login, {
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      console.log('succ');
      let {
        token,
        tokenExpiresAt,
        user: { firstname }
      } = data;
      setCheckTokenStatus(token);
      localStorage.setItem('idToken', JSON.stringify(token));
      localStorage.setItem('expires', JSON.stringify(tokenExpiresAt));
      navigate('/dashboard', {
        replace: true
      });
      addToast(`hello ${firstname}!`, { appearance: 'success', autoDismiss: true, autoDismissTimeout: 3000 });
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      console.log(error);
      addToast(`error: ${error}`, {
        appearance: 'error',
        autoDismiss: true,
        autoDismissTimeout: 3000
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```js
/** @format */
//AuthController
import myAPI from '../../config/api/index';

export default class AuthController {
  static async Login(mobile, password) {
    let data = {
      mobile,
      password,
      role: 1
    };
    try {
      const response = await myAPI.post(`/login`, data);
      return response.data;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('error occured');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, in your question, it appears that the API returns the error in the body of a 200 response. How do you detect that it in fact failed?

Comment: you need to show the code for  `AuthController.Login` please. Most likely, it doesn't return a rejected promise in error cases!

Comment: @TkDodo Hi, I have already updated my question

Comment: @TkDodo, what's the http code returned in that case from the api ?

Comment: @YassineCHABLI 401

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling unauthorized request in react-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63015103/handling-unauthorized-request-in-react-query)

Comment: So the hack behind is to check the status (if it's 401 or 404) in the api call and throw an exception so you can catch it from the onError of the react query.

Comment: try getting rid of the try catch block, let the error propagate and it will most likely call the right callback